# Nativescript: how to store HTTP values to public variables

Tags: javascript, android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have some problem here, I'm using a mix of Angular2 and Nativescript's native JS to use HTTP because I was having problems with Angular2 HTTP before this implementation, but I'm having frustration on how to put the JSON response from the http request to the monthList variable so it can be read all over the place. Please help, Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
public monthList = [];


    constructor(location: Location, private page: Page, private router: Router, private testing: any) {
        this.router = router;
        this.testing = testing;
        let http = require("http");


        http.getJSON("link")
            .then(function (r) {
                // Argument (r) is JSON!
            }, function (e) {
                // Argument (e) is Error!
                console.log(e);
            });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your .then you set your return object to your monthList

```
this.monthList = r;
```

Try doing a console.dump(r) and see what is being returned. You may have to do something like r.xxx or however it is structured.

Then you can probably do something like

```
this.monthList.month
```

and access the data of the month and so forth. Or you maybe have to do something like

```
this.monthList[0].month.
```

For example in my project I have a JSON object coming back that is nested and I need to set it as something like r.value.data.

Comment: will try it later… but I think I tried this before but didn't work… just a reminder… this is a require inside the angular2 of nativescript… :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific issue you're running into? I would think its as simple as:

```
class SomeAngularClass {
  constructor() {
    http.getJSON("link")
      .then(function(r) {
        this.monthList.push(r);
      }, function (e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
}
```

And then you could access it via:

```
SomeAngularClass().monthList;
```

Comment: mostly the console returns uncaught in promise type of errors… then display only blank in the android emulator…